# How can place some text and a transparent color in a background image in html?

Tags: html, css

How can I place some text and a transparent background color on a background image in html/css ?
An example I have attached here,
[image]
Please help me

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code.

```
 body {
        background: white url(479616460.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
    .header {
        background-color: #8DCC3A;
        border-top: 60px solid #4A5C61;
        margin-left: 20%;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    .title {
        left: 21.5%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        width: 57%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="title">
        <h1></h1>
        <h2></h2> </div>
</body>
```

thanks.

Comment: Why do people negative-vote this answer? It's correct and works as intended!

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
```

The `255` is the **R** value, first `0` is the **G** value, last `0` is the **B** value and the `0.3` is the **A** the transparency `0.3` equals to `30%`.

**RGBA** meaning is Red Green Blue Alpha

In case you were using `hex` color codes before, [here](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/) you can convert the `hex` color code to `rgba` and fill in the opacity you want in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo `HTML & CSS` structure for you hope it helps [Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfhdfmjh/5/)

```
<div class="mainDiv">
  <img src="http://pidesigns.in/images/residencial-works-banner.png">
  <div class="subdiv">
    <h1>
      Hello World!
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>


.mainDiv{
  position:relative;
}
.subdiv{
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: its working fine in browser, but my aim is to make an email newsletter. I have used inline code, but its not successfully working in email. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Can you please share your code??